# jmeter auto create user/password account

Tags: linux, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to use jmeter to simulate 500 usernames/passwords being created on a test site I have. The home page has 3 fields, username,email address, and password. How can I get jmeter to auto-fill those fields? 
The next question is can jmeter then go to the next page and fill in credit information for example?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note here is JMeter is not like QTP / Selenium. It is not a pure functional testing tool.
However, It can be used for functional testing when you know how to use it!

For your question,

- Record the http requests for creating the user and entering the credit information. Check this for more information. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
- Then update the recorded scripts to parameterize the username, password email etc
- Then you can update the loop count to rerun it again and again to create the data you want to create

JMeter is an excellent tool for performance testing, functional testing and for creating test data etc.

Comment: The proxy thing didn't work at all. Can't I just do a post request and enter the parameter fields?

Comment: Please provide more details - what does not work. What is the issue you face.

Comment: Actually, I managed to get this to work. I found a tutorial on setting up a recorder (I did not know there was a template built in). I then found the forms I needed digging through the recordings and worked off of those. Next step is to simulate tokens from dummy payments.

Comment: Great that you got that working. Please refer to this. Thi slink shows how to parameterize. http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can auto generate a credit card token?

Comment: Thanks! If I want to have jmeter simulating users logging in and streaming video can jmeter keep them logged in to stream?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter has possibility to use either external pre-defined data or generate some random values.

To use existing username/password/email combinations there are following options:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)- to read information from CSV files
- [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) - to fetch information from any database which supports JDBC protocol
- [StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) - to read a string from file
- [CSVRead](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) - similar to CSV Data Set Config
- [RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - to generate a random string

In regards to "go to the next page", it is also possible given that you have a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Remember that JMeter acts on protocol level so you'll need to properly construct HTTP Requests.

The best way to trace execution and visualize requests/responses is using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.